# How to replace an element in an array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a COLLECTION `collflokks` in MongoDB, sample Document is :-

```
{   
    "_id" : "b_8AUL",   
    "f_name" : "Pizza. Hut",   
    "f_lat" : "22.7523513",   
    "f_lng" : "75.9225847",   
    "c_uid" : "33",   
    "f_type" : NumberLong(3),   
    "members" : [     
        "42",     
        "43"   
    ]   
}
```

Within the "members" array , I want to add Arrays like `{id:42,name:Mark}` , `{id:43,name:Hughes}`
Currently i'm adding just ids(eg.42,43). I'm only concerned about the new data as it will have new ids .Please suggest.

Earlier I was using this code to push into the members Array:

```
$flokkCollection = 'collFlokks';
$flokkCollection->update(
       array("_id" => $f_handle), 
       array('$push' => array("members" => $u_id))
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if what you are asking here is "replacing your existing data" then you need to "loop" the results from the collection and "replace" the array content that exists with your new format.

There are likely smarter ways to approach this, but you are not really giving us all the required information in your question, so I can only answer in the basic terms.

Presuming you have:

```
$required = array(
   array(array("id" => "42"), array("name" => "Mark")),
   array(array("id" => "43"), array("name" => "Hughes"))
);
```

As input, then you do something like this:

```
function myMapper($v) {
    return $v["id"];
}

$mapped = array_map("myMapper",$required);

foreach( $mapped as $value) {

    $filtered = array_values(
        array_filter($required,function($k) {
            return $k["id"] == $value;
        })
    )[0];

    collection.update(array(
        array("members" => $value),
        array('$set' => array( 
            "members.$" => $filtered
        ))
    ));
}
```

Which should use the [positional `$` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to find the matched "position" of the array element by the value used in the "query" portion of the update statement, then in the "update" portion of that statement [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) that current array index to the new value at the "filtered" content index from the original input array.

Outside of PHP. We call these inner elements "objects" and not "arrays" which is a PHP notation trait. Key/value things are "objects" and "lists" are "arrays".

Comment: I'm Sorry to have not provided proper info as I'm not used to asking Questions here. Actually , I wanted to change the functionality to push into the array with the new way - id & name ... i think I solved it using :-              $user_data = array(
                                         'uid' => $u_id,
                                         'name'  => "Dishu"                                                   
                                       );                                                            array('$push' => array("members" => $user_data)));

Comment: @dgcoder It's not that much of an issue beyonf my point is that there are probably better ways to get the mapping of "Mark" and "Hughes" to the relevant "id" values in what you are really trying to do. This should at least give a guide to the general process anyway.

Comment: @dgcoder You didn't "solve it". You either need to "remove" or "replace" as this example shows you how to do, the existing array members. Otherwise you just end up with the existing array members and the addition of "new" members, which is clearly what you **do not** want.

Comment: Now my members section of document looks like :                                                        "members" : [ 
        {
            "uid" : "42",
            "name" : "Dishu"
        }

Comment: Thanks @Blakes, Actually existing data does not matter to me as of now because i'm still developing my product. However, this code will surely help me if I need to change an existing Data.

Comment: @dgcoder You still cannot `$push` to an existing array that removes the things that are there. Therefore what "you think" is correct is not correct. You didn't solve this by yourself.

Comment: Do you mean to say next time another $user_data is pushed into "members" , the previous data will be removed ? According to my code.                        $flokkCollection->update(
       array("_id" => $f_handle), 
       array('$push' => array("members" =>  $user_data))
);

Comment: @dgcoder You clearly have not even looked at your data in result. Because if you had you would clearly see: `"members" : [  "42", "43",{ "id": "42","name": "Mark"} ,{ "id": "43", "name": "Hughes" } ]`. Which exactly why you **cannot just $push**. You need to **replace** at the matched array index to just have `"members" : [{ "id": "42","name": "Mark"} ,{ "id": "43", "name": "Hughes" } ]`. And that should be very simple to understand.

Comment: @dgcoder Did you? I don't see an accept on the answer which actualy does what I am saying it does.